# Android Parser de soapFault

Tags: android, web-service, parse

Bom estou começando a fazer tramento de erros que o webService soap me retorna, como por exemplo se o usúario digitar login ou senha errado o web service retorna um erro SoapFault: usuario ou senha invalido. Só que não consigo pegar essa mensagem e mostrar em Toast para alertar sobre o problema. Como eu poderia resolver isso, por nos java acontece uma exception do try catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi da seguinte maneira, no metodo onde chamo o *Web Service* para verificar o login usei a seguinte verificação:

```
 if(envelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapFault) {
     strFault = ((SoapFault) envelope.bodyIn).faultstring

 }
```

E no `try catch` onde o método é chamado onde chegava o erro da `Exception` chamei uma `thread` com um `toast`.

```
finally {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ws.strFault, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    dialog.dismiss();
}
```